# Ошибка создания bean Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

начал погружаться в Spring Boot и решил написать учебный проект "Библиотека "  c такими технологиями как Spring Boot, Spring Jdbc и Spring Shell. 
При старте приложения возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-10 22:04:49.770 ERROR 5049 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'libraryCommandLine' defined in file [/Users/mac/Developer/otus_spring/otus_spring4/target/classes/ru/evgeny/otus_spring4/servise/LibraryCommandLine.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shellLibraryService' defined in file [/Users/mac/Developer/otus_spring/otus_spring4/target/classes/ru/evgeny/otus_spring4/servise/impl/ShellLibraryService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at ru.evgeny.otus_spring4.Application.main(Application.java:31) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shellLibraryService' defined in file [/Users/mac/Developer/otus_spring/otus_spring4/target/classes/ru/evgeny/otus_spring4/servise/impl/ShellLibraryService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1279) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ru.evgeny.otus_spring4.servise.impl.ShellLibraryService$1.<init>(ShellLibraryService.java:123) ~[classes/:na]
    at ru.evgeny.otus_spring4.servise.impl.ShellLibraryService.<clinit>(ShellLibraryService.java:122) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Не могу никак понять почему Spring не может создать ShellLibraryService??? Вот код основных классов, а целиком приложение на https://github.com/evgenyrybishew/otus-spring/tree/master/otus_spring4

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public JdbcOperations jdbcOperations(LoadDbSettings settings) {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setUrl(settings.getDbUrl());
        ds.setDriverClassName(settings.getDbDriver());
        ds.setUsername(settings.getDbUser());
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

ShellLibraryService:

```
@Service
public class ShellLibraryService implements IShellDataBaseServise {

    private AuthorDao authorDao;
    private BookDao bookDao;
    private GenreDao genreDao;
    private PublisherDao publisherDao;


    @Autowired
    public ShellLibraryService(AuthorDao authorDao, BookDao bookDao, GenreDao genreDao, PublisherDao publisherDao) {
        this.authorDao = authorDao;
        this.bookDao = bookDao;
        this.genreDao = genreDao;
        this.publisherDao = publisherDao;
    }


    @Override
    public void initTables() {
        initAllTables();
        fillGenreTable();
        fillAuthorTable();
        fillPublisherTable();
        fillBookTable();
    }

    //continue -> https://github.com/evgenyrybishew/otus-spring/tree/master/otus_spring4
```

LibraryCommandLine:

```
@ShellComponent
public class LibraryCommandLine {
    private IShellDataBaseServise cli;

    @Autowired
    public LibraryCommandLine(IShellDataBaseServise cli) {
        this.cli = cli;
    }


    @ShellMethod("Start")
    public void start() {
        cli.initTables();
    }

    @ShellMethod("Search book by autor's name")
    public void searchn(@ShellOption String name) {
        cli.searchBookByAuthorName(name);
    }


    @ShellMethod("Search book by autor's lastname")
    public void searchl(@ShellOption String name) {
        cli.searchBookByAuthorLastName(name);
    }


    @ShellMethod("Search book by name")
    public void searchb(@ShellOption String name) {
        cli.searchBookByName(name);
    }


    @ShellMethod("Search book by publisher's name")
    public void searchp(@ShellOption String name) {
        cli.searchBookByPublisher(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка(`NullPointerException`) при инициализации `HashMap`'ов.
Видел много всяких, но не припомню такого метода инициализации.
В них Вы пытаетесь сразу же обратиться к переменной, которую вы только пытаетесь объявить и закономерно получаете NPE.

```
private static final Map<String, Genre> genreMap = new HashMap<String, Genre>(){{
    genreMap.put(BUSINESS_LITERATURE, new Genre(1, BUSINESS_LITERATURE));
    genreMap.put(DETECTIVES_AND_THRILLERS, new Genre(2, DETECTIVES_AND_THRILLERS));
    genreMap.put(DOCUMENTARY_LITERATURE, new Genre(3, DOCUMENTARY_LITERATURE));
    genreMap.put(DRAMATURGY, new Genre(4, DRAMATURGY));
    genreMap.put(ART_ART_HISTORY_DESIGN, new Genre(5, ART_ART_HISTORY_DESIGN));
    genreMap.put(COMPUTERS_AND_INTERNET, new Genre(6, COMPUTERS_AND_INTERNET));
    genreMap.put(SCIENCE_EDUCATION, new Genre(7, SCIENCE_EDUCATION));
}};
```

...

```
private static Map<String, Author> authorMap = new HashMap<String, Author>(){{
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR1, new Author(1, AUTHOR1.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR1.split(" ")[1]));
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR2, new Author(1, AUTHOR2.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR2.split(" ")[1]));
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR3, new Author(1, AUTHOR3.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR3.split(" ")[1] + AUTHOR3.split(" ")[2]));
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR4, new Author(1, AUTHOR4.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR4.split(" ")[1] + AUTHOR4.split(" ")[2]));
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR5, new Author(1, AUTHOR4.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR4.split(" ")[1]));
}};
```

Замените их на:

```
private static final Map<String, Genre> genreMap;
static {
    genreMap = new HashMap<String, Genre>();
    genreMap.put(BUSINESS_LITERATURE, new Genre(1, BUSINESS_LITERATURE));
    genreMap.put(DETECTIVES_AND_THRILLERS, new Genre(2, DETECTIVES_AND_THRILLERS));
    genreMap.put(DOCUMENTARY_LITERATURE, new Genre(3, DOCUMENTARY_LITERATURE));
    genreMap.put(DRAMATURGY, new Genre(4, DRAMATURGY));
    genreMap.put(ART_ART_HISTORY_DESIGN, new Genre(5, ART_ART_HISTORY_DESIGN));
    genreMap.put(COMPUTERS_AND_INTERNET, new Genre(6, COMPUTERS_AND_INTERNET));
    genreMap.put(SCIENCE_EDUCATION, new Genre(7, SCIENCE_EDUCATION));
}
```

...

```
private static Map<String, Author> authorMap;
static {
    authorMap = new HashMap<String, Author>();
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR1, new Author(1, AUTHOR1.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR1.split(" ")[1]));
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR2, new Author(1, AUTHOR2.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR2.split(" ")[1]));
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR3, new Author(1, AUTHOR3.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR3.split(" ")[1] + AUTHOR3.split(" ")[2]));
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR4, new Author(1, AUTHOR4.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR4.split(" ")[1] + AUTHOR4.split(" ")[2]));
    authorMap.put(AUTHOR5, new Author(1, AUTHOR4.split(" ")[0], AUTHOR4.split(" ")[1]));
}
```

результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылки:
[Способы инициализации Map'ов](https://www.baeldung.com/java-initialize-hashmap)